# Why was Gimli of such a low rank, compared to the other representatives chosen for the Fellowship?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

Part of the members of the Fellowship were chosen as representatives of their race: Legolas for the Elves, Boromir for mankind and Gimli for the dwarves. Of those three, two were the heirs of a ruler at the time (king Thranduil and the steward Denethor, who was de-facto king). Gimli, however, is simply the "son of Glóin", who, while surely significant, is of much lesser rank than the other two. According to [this family tree](https://mulubinba.typepad.com/.a/6a00d8341dd88553ef0148c7e88771970c-pi), Gimli's most common ancestor with Dáin II Ironfoot, the ruler of his house at the time, was four to five generations in the past.

**My question is:** Why was Gimli, as the representatives of the dwarves, of such a low rank, compared to the other representatives? Furthermore, is this fact of larger significance?

Comment: Denethor, alas, was never part of a royal family in England.  His family styled themselves _stewards_.

Comment: My bad, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: Me think the movie made Gimli the resident "comic relief" and that overshadowed his role as depicted in the book.

Comment: @Max - pretty much correct, unfortunately.  At least after the Fellowship split, it was obvious that Gimli was the comic relief in his group.  In the first movie it was more Merry and (particularly) Pippin.

Comment: Yep! forgot about those two! thanks.

Comment: They are ranked by height, Gimli was too short

Comment: Sam was also part of the fellowship. He was a gardener, so I don't think Gimli was quite the lowest-ranked member of the fellowship.

Comment: Ah yes I believe his name was styled Sam, son of The Old Gaffer

Comment: @reirab: But Sam was not invited to the Elrond Council. His presence, as well as Merry and Pippin participations to these events is accidental, and only due to his friendship with Frodo. Even Frodo as a member of the Fellowship is unexpected (nobody thought he would decide to go to the Moria).

Comment: @Taladris He wasn't invited to the Council, but he was part of the Fellowship from its inception. It wasn't decided until the conclusion of the Council that there would be a Fellowship.

Comment: This is from the top of my head: Well, I never thought that Gimli was actually a representative. I always thought that the real representative from the lonely mountain was Gloin (also present in the council, at least in the books). Gimli was just part of his retinue. There were many people in Rivendell those days who weren't high lords or important representatives, they were just acompanying important people. This is the case with Merry and Pippin. Gimli, on the other hand, was present in the council, unlike Merry&Pippin, probably because his father asked for it.

Comment: The whole "Fellowship" was just Elrond's ploy to get rid of uninvited guests who overstayed their welcome: one filthy human who was after his daughter, one redneck wood-elf, one filthy dwarf, one human who was too full of himself just because his daddy was a glorified janitor, four monkeys and one meddlesome Maia. It mostly worked.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is not significant.

The Council of Elrond was *not* convened in order to choose members of a Fellowship, but rather to discuss the matter of the Ring.  Choosing members of the Fellowship was just something that happened after Frodo volunteering to take the Ring to Mordor, and the members were chosen from those who were in Rivendell at the time.

Glóin and Gimli just happened to be the Dwarves who were there (as ambassadors from Dáin), and therefore Gimli was the one chosen by Elrond (Glóin presumably being too old):

> For the rest, they shall represent the other Free Peoples of the World: Elves, Dwarves, and Men. Legolas shall be for the Elves; and Gimli son of Glóin for the Dwarves. They are willing to go at least to the passes of the Mountains, and maybe beyond. For men you shall have Aragorn son of Arathorn, for the Ring of Isildur concerns him closely.

The fact that those chosen for Elves and Men happened to be heirs is not relevant; Elrond was perfectly willing to choose other Elves who were *not* heirs or the final two members (before Merry and Pippin came onboard):

> 'There remain two more to be found,' said Elrond. 'These I will consider. Of my household I may find some that it seems good to me to send.'

Finally I should note that you're downplaying the rank of Gimli; as the son of Glóin he is also the son of one of the Dwarves who did the Quest of Erebor, and the son of an ambassador from one of the greatest Dwarf kingdoms, as we learn when Glóin is first introduced:

> Next to Frodo on his right sat **a dwarf of important appearance**, richly dressed. His beard, very long and forked, was white, nearly as white as the snow-white cloth of his garments. He wore a silver belt, and round his neck hung a chain of silver and diamonds.

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Comment: I wonder if Elrond was considering sending Arwen with them. Camping out isn't pretty; a few weeks/months of sleeping on the ground, with no regular baths, no makeup, no toilets, etc. and they might get over each other. ;)

Comment: @JoeL. "Get over each other" Who might get over each other? Aragorn and Arwen? Elrond wasn't too fond of his daughter dating a human, but he respects Aragorn and doesn't forbid them to see each other.

Comment: Joke: (noun) Something said or done to evoke laughter or amusement, especially an amusing story with a punch line.

Comment: @JoeL. - we're lucky he didn't send Tauriel!!!

Comment: @MattGutting - yours still has the main point though - they were chosen because they just happened to be the ones who were there.

Comment: And even those at the Council of Elrond weren't chosen for any particular reason, but just because they happened to be there - "called, I say, though I have not called you..."

Comment: It always seemed to me like Gimli was there for largely political reasons; the token dwarf, as it were

Comment: @Kevin Indeed, forcing them to go on a long and possibly fruitless quest together would be the opposite of forbidding them from seeing each other--and if it just so happens to dissuade them from continuing their courtship, so much the better (from Elrond's perspective)!

Comment: To reinforce your last point, Gimli's great-great-great grandfather was Nain II, King of Durin's Folk. He was Dwarf royalty.

Comment: @Jason I believe the hobbits were more tokin' then the rest of them, except perhaps Gandalf. Oh, wrong tokin'. My bad.

Comment: @Plutor - agreed, he may not be a direct prince but he's close to a similar rank within whatever passes for the Dwarven hierarchy.

Comment: The fellowship needed to have at least one dwarf for tossing, so it had to be Gimli... after all would you want to be the one to try tossing Thorin??

Answer (score 31):

Let's begin by correcting what appears to be a misunderstanding: In the book, at least (I don't remember about the movie), Aragorn, not Boromir, is the one chosen as the representative of Men. Boromir is chosen simply because he and Aragorn happen to be going the same way as the Fellowship:

> "I thought you were going to Minas Tirith with Boromir."
>
> "I am," said Aragorn. "... But your road and our road lie together for many hundreds of miles. Therefore Boromir will also be in the Company."

(*Lord of the Rings*, Book II, Chapter 2, "The Council of Elrond")

The others are not chosen because of anything about them, as far as I can tell. Legolas and Gimli were chosen apparently because they happened to be there, at the Council.

As far as any greater significance: there is none. Nothing is ever made either of Legolas' position as the heir apparent, nor of Gimli's lack of such position.

Comment: DAMN good point @Matt and very, very subtle.

Answer (score 13):

Huh? None of the Hobbits really had rank.  Even if we take Frodo as Esquire and assume his cousins are of equal rank (if esquire even probably means diddly to Hobbits) Sam's still just a gardener. Gimli while not heir apparent still has a good solid claim to the throne.

So Dáin II Ironfoot is king.

Heir apparent is his son Thorin III Stonehelm

Since I couldn't find a DOB for Durin VII (Thorin III Stonehelm's son)...I'm going to assume he wasn't born yet

Next would be Balin but he's dead....granted they don't know it at the time...

So Dwalin is 2nd in line for the throne

After Dwalin would be Óin...but Óin is also dead so...

Glóin is 3rd in line and Gimli is his heir

4th isn't an insignificant spot...especially in times of war (something about rulers personally leading the troops does that).  It's certainly higher than Boromir being son of Denethor as Stewards are ultimately just high ranking servants.

That said the Fellowship was a group of **VOLUNTEERS** and weren't chosen by any save themselves.

Comment: "Huh? None of the Hobbits really had rank." I know and thus I made the question about the characters included in the fellowship specifically to represent the free peoples of middle-earth; non of the hobbit was part of the fellowship for that reason.

Comment: @Mort but they were still from a free people. And as I said looking at the others steward is still a servant.

Comment: "None of the Hobbits really had rank" - huh?  Pippin was the heir of the Thain, who was the King's representative in the Shire and nominal head of State; Merry was the heir of the house of Brandybuck, which is roughly the Thain's equivalent east of the Brandywine.  Frodo *was* the head of the Baggins family which makes him the most prominent hobbit in Hobbiton.  The Shire is based on 19th century England ("about the year of Queen Victoria's Diamond Jubilee" according to Tolkien), and those three are effectively heads of the local government.

Comment: I'm glad you brought that up @jcast - no one ever does. They were basically the big men on campus before they left. When they came back as heroes of the War of the Ring, they were as close to kings as Hobbits ever get.

Comment: "That said the Fellowship was a group of VOLUNTEERS and weren't chosen by any save themselves" - not quite true; in the movies they certainly were, but in the books many of them were actually chosen by Elrond.

Comment: Err Pippin and Merry are high ranking hobbit nobles look at the family trees! Frodo also a took albeit aminor one adopted into a nouveau riche family the SB having mad all their money in "trade"

Comment: @JonathanCast - The hobbits are definitely upper-class toffs, I'll grant, but their "nobility" is minimal. For instance, in terms of authority, the Thain was something of a mayor, meaning that Pippin is not even the mayor, just someone related to him. There hardly appears to even be a local government in the Shire, relegating  Pippin and Merry to rich folks who can brag about their family trees. That does not really compare to "heir to the realm of Gondor" or "son of the Elf-King."

Answer (score 11):

Gimli wasn't of a low rank.  As Glóin's son he had a very high rank among the dwarves of Durin's people — both in his own right and through the acclaim of winning back the Lonely Mountain.

Within the company none had 'ranks' really — other than Gandalf who was chosen specifically to lead and Aragorn who was in many ways his foster-son and given his knowledge of the world the natural choice to take over if Gandalf was not on hand.

Just look at the make-up of the company:

- Gandalf - chief Maia of Irmo/Lórien and later chief of the other Istari.
- Aragorn - king of both Arnor and Gondor, whether Denethor liked it or not.
- Legolas - Sinda-prince and heir to Northern Mirkwood/Greenwood.
- Gimli - son of dwarven nobility.
- Boromir - heir to steward of one of the two Realms in Exile.
- Pippin - eldest child and heir to the actual 'chief' of the shire.
- Merry - wealthy counterpart to Pippin in the colony beside the Brandywine.
- Frodo - SUPER-wealthy adopted heir to one of - if not THE - richest Hobbit in the shire.
- Sam - Gardner...  Poor Sam.

Really they were all of very similar 'rank' with Gandalf, Legolas and Aragon at the 'top' as measured from outside.  From within though it really didn't matter — they chose to follow Gandalf and chose to help Frodo.

Answer (score 4):

### Introduction

This answer is based upon my recollection of reading the books a few years ago, as well as the [LotR Wiki.](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page)

### Answer

He was attending not as much as a direct representative of the King Under the Mountain, but as a companion of the Representative of the King Under the Mountain.

As can be read [here](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Gimli), Glóin had come to Rivendell seeking the advice of Elrond and he brought his son, Gimli, there.

As can be read [here](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Council_of_Elrond), Gimli's father [Glóin](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Gl%C3%B3in), attended the Council as the Representative for the King Under the Mountain. Gloín had, as mentioned above, brought Gimli along as part of his entourage, and he was, thus, invited to join the council.

Answer (score 3):

All of the members of the council represented their race. However, they were never sent for with the council in mind. Besides Gandalf, Aragorn, and the Hobbits; the others were seeking Elrond's council on other matters and as fate would have it been available for the council being the Fellowship affected all of Middle-earth

Comment: +1 I wish I could upvote this more than once.  It is important to remember that the representatives were never called for.  They all gathered at that important time to seek Elrond's counsel. Dain obviously thought Gloin more than important enough for that task.

Answer (score 2):

Gimli was a member of the dynasty of Durin, and thus just a few lives away from becoming king of the most honored and prestigious royal family of his species.  There were only a tiny handful of dwarves senior in rank and prestige to Gimli.